# Best practice to best illustrate side navbar children

Tags: navigation, sidebar, background

I have this Side Navbar with children. I am not sure that the way I am illustrating  the children is the best way of doing this.

Questions - Is this the best way for me to illustrate navbar item's children? Is there more I can do to improve presentation?

```
primary: "#33404D",
secondary: "#465666",
accent: "#FFAB00"
```

First Attempt - Take 1(Oldest version of the component)

[image]

Second Attempt - Take 2

[image]

Third Attempt - Take 3

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you'll find any "best practice" for this particular module. But here are some visual cues for the user to better understand the level changes.

- The change in arrow direction with an animated pull-down of the child entities. (It draws the user's attention)
- Use of fading colors is generally used to show change in levels. I would avoid using darker background colors for the child entities because unless there's a drop-shadow under the parent level, it is very hard to tell which is the parent and which is the child. A fade in color (dropping saturation) is a much more natural way of showing level-ins.
- **Avoid indentation at all costs!** Although good for giving a clear sign of level-in, it will cause space issues if you have multiple levels and/or long menu item labels. The text also gets completely messed up if viewed in lower resolutions, smaller screens or larger text sizes as you'd see very few characters once you're 1 or 2 levels down. The missing icons and change of background color are enough.

**Alternates**

You can, instead, go for an indented list (I believe it's called hierarchy view). It's more common in documentation websites, not so much so for regular sites or web-applications.

Or, a pop-out menu where the level-ins are pop-outs.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it better just with typography changes:

1. Increasing the left indent

[image: left indent]

2. Decreasing the font-weight

[image: font-weight]

3. Using the icon color

[image: icon color]